# Does Minecraft Java server lag more when in online-mode=false?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I am starting a smp in a few days.
While testing I saw `online-mode=true` lagged less than `online-mode=false`

Does `offline-mode` lag more than `online-mode`?
If yes how do I eliminate it?

Comment: Well apparently the Mod themselves deleted the part of piracy thing. I guess the rule only applies for question asker? Besides, this question itself is informative so... I guess it's fine now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Short Answer

No. But don't do it anyway.

## Slightly Longer Answer

### Online Mode

If online mode is enabled, when a player joins, they are checked against Mojang's servers. If they do not match, they are not allowed into the game.

This effectively means that if someone wants to join the server as you, they'll also need access to your Microsoft/Mojang account. You should be more worried if you are hacked on an online server than an offline one.

If you do not have an internet connection, no players will be able to join in online mode.

Unless you have a specific reason to disable it, don't, as it also enables the usage of player skins, and since you are running an SMP, you cannot change your mind easily - all inventories and other player data will be lost.

If you are running a public server, definitely don't.

### Offline Mode

Offline mode does not make a difference in terms of performance, and definitely not a negative one. It actually shaves a few seconds off the login time, but still doesn't effect the overall performance, as this is handled separately.

Offline mode simply disables authentication, meaning that the server does not know if I player is who they say they are.

In offline mode, any player joining the game is allowed in with whatever name they please. If there is a whitelist, it will still work, but a player can bypass it by changing their name.

However, offline mode does have its advantages. If you do not have access to the internet, you can still continue to play on your locally hosted server. If you are messing around with Bukkit plugins while in a car ([but not if you're driving it](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Splash)), or in space (as you often do) this may be useful. Of course, you can use a Wi-Fi Hotspot on your phone (unless in space), or just use a single-player world.

Offline mode is also useful if you want to be able to use any username. For example, if you are working on a multiplayer Minecraft minigame, it can be useful to test it with multiple players, without buying another account. It can also be used if your friend does not own a Minecraft account, and they want to try the game before buying it. *

* I'm not encouraging piracy. I just don't personally consider this to be piracy, and I'm assumming that Arqade doesn't consider this to be piracy, since they didn't take down other threads discussing this.

Answer (score 2):

No it does not. Online mode is connected to Mojangs multiplayer code meaning that pirated versions of the game like Tlauncher cant join servers like Hypixel or PVP legacy.